# What is Chef doing when I use the `s3cmd` recipe?

Tags: amazon-s3, chef-infra, s3cmd

I am using Chef and [this s3cmd cookbook](https://github.com/fred/chef-s3cmd).

As [this tutorial](http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/first-steps-with-chef.html) says I use `knife` to download and tar it. I actually made `s3cmd` work following the tutorial instructions, but I have problems understanding where exactly the installation of `s3cmd` is happening?

Can anyone explain to me what Chef is doing when using the s3cmd recipe?

Comment: Could you link to the recipe and tutorial you are using? What have you added to your nodes run list? Have you looked at DEBUG logs for the `chef-client` run?

Comment: I use this tutorial: http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/first-steps-with-chef.html

Comment: And I use this for my s3cmd configuration : https://github.com/fred/chef-s3cmd

Comment: Ok. So you have added the recipe to a node's run list and it has installed `s3cmd` successfully? You just want to know how?

Comment: Yes, everything works, I just don't see where and how chef installs it for me, I need to know in order to administer my server correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `chef-solo` locally (or `chef-client` in a server setup) you are telling Chef to compile a set of [resources](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/resources.html) defined in your cookbooks recipes to then be applied to the [node](https://docs.getchef.com/chef_overview_nodes.html) you are running the command on.

A resource defines the tasks and settings for something you want to setup.

The `run_list` set for the node defines what cookbook recipes will be compiled.

#### s3cmd

In your case, your `run_list` will have probably been `recipe[s3cmd]`.

This instructs Chef to look in the `s3cmd` cookbook and as you didn't give a specific recipe, it loads [`s3cmd/recipes/default.rb`](https://github.com/fred/chef-s3cmd/blob/3cf79243c7ccf9f4bef1bf03817c8246a15ab367/recipes/default.rb).

If you gave a specific recipe, like `recipe[s3_cmd::other]` then Chef would load the file `s3_cmd/recipes/other.rb`.

Chef will compile all the [resources](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/resources.html) defined in the recipe(s) into a list and the run through the list applying changes as required to your system.

#### What `s3cmd::default` does

1. First it installs some [`package`s](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_package.html) (via your distributions package manager)

   ```
   python, python-setuptools, python-distutils-extra, python-dateutil, s3cmd
   ```

   *Note*: This is entirely different to what the [readme](https://github.com/fred/chef-s3cmd/blob/3cf79243c7ccf9f4bef1bf03817c8246a15ab367/README.md) says about how `s3cmd` is installed! Always check!
2. Figures out where the config should go.

   ```
   if node['s3cmd']['config_dir']
     home_folder = node['s3cmd']['config_dir']
   else
     home_folder = node['etc']['passwd'][node['s3cmd']['user']]['dir']
   end
   ```
3. Creates the `.s3cfg` config file from a [`template`](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbook_templates.html) in the [cookbook](https://github.com/fred/chef-s3cmd/blob/3cf79243c7ccf9f4bef1bf03817c8246a15ab367/templates/default/s3cfg.erb).

   ```
   template "#{home_folder}/.s3cfg" do...
   ```

#### What else

Cookbooks can also define their own [resources and providers](https://docs.getchef.com/resource.html) to create more reusable cookbooks.  The resource names and attributes will be defined in `cookbook/resources/blah.rb`. The code for each resource `action` will be in `cookbook/providers/blah.rb`

Code can be packaged in `cookbook/libraries/blah.rb` and included in other Ruby files.

Run `chef-solo` with the `--log-level DEBUG` option and step through the output. Try and identify the run list compilation phase, and then where everything is being applied.